# Attach js into mojoPortal

Tags: javascript, asp.net, mojoportal

I have wrote JS calculator and need include it into mojoPortal site. I have upload js files to directory /calculator/ and add script tags at page content. But when browser request http://example.com/calculator/calculator.js it get 500 error:

Runtime Error

Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

How I can disable execution of this folder or attach files in code?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to open the javascript file directly from the webserver you need to embed it in a web page like this:

```
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js"></script></head>
<body><p>Code running...</p></body>
</html>
```

In terms using javascript in Mojoportal, there is a custom javascript module which you can use to insert javascript into a Mojoportal page [see adding custom javascript](http://www.mojoportal.com/adding-custom-javascript.aspx)